# How to use shortcut operators (?. ??) in this case?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.6.1

Here is simplified version of my code.

```
class Address
{
    public bool IsAppartment { get; set; }
}

class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
} 

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       Employee employee = new Employee()
       {
           Name = "Charlie"
       };
       if (employee.Address == null || !employee.Address.IsAppartment)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Hello in if");
       }
       else
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Hello in else");
       }
   }
}
```

Is there any way to re-write following line of code using any of the short operators such as ?. or ?? or any other ones?

> ```
> if (employee.Address == null || !employee.Address.IsAppartment)
> ```

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. The solution from that question here causes a compilation error.

Comment: This is fully addressed in the answers and comments to your other recent question.

Comment: `if (!employee.Address?.IsApartment ?? true)` The part before the `??` is evaluated first. If that has a `null` value, then the right side is evaluated and returned (and you want to return `true` for null, so we just use `true`). If it doesn't have a `null` value, then the left value is returned. The exclamation point before employee is a ["logical negation" operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators) - if `IsApartment` is `false`, the exclamation point flips it to `true`.

Answer (score -2):

Yes. The whole point of the `?.` operator is to avoid checking for null in situations like this. Simply write:

```
if (employee.Address?.IsAppartment)
```

Comment: Cannot convert `bool?` to `bool`.

Comment: This does not return `true` when `employee.Address == null`.

Comment: Then I don't understand the question? If he wants to return true when Address is null, OR when the IsApartment property is true, those are two totally different scenarios and there's no way to avoid having two conditions.

Comment: If you want `true` when `employee.Address == null`, you have to add `?? true` to the end of the expression you wrote. Otherwise, add `?? false`. Either way, you need to do something with the `null` you get when `employee.Address == null` or else you get a compiler error.